# Error trying to install OpenOffice or LibreOffice after removing OpenOffice

Tags: 10.04, libreoffice, openoffice.org

1. I removed OpenOffice with `isuru@isuru-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get purge "openoffice*"`
2. Now when I try to install LibreOffice I get following error 
   [image]

Please help me to install LibreOffice on my computer. Im om Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get update`?

Comment: If you are still using **10.04 LTS**, then there is a stable version of **OpenOffice.org** (pre Apache OpenOffice, pre LibreOffice) that works fine.

Comment: OpenOffice.Org is bit slower than libre. That's why i'm switching.

Answer (score 2):

oooh mate what you have done....

In debian apt is wonderful command and play with it careful. Now as i understand your scenario. You are trying to remove your Office package. Remove packages from synaptic or software-manager is kind of easy, but through apt it might create problem sometime.

Before doing anything with apt, please take backup of /var/lib/dpkg/status and /var/lib/dpkg/avialable file. If anything goes wrong these files will help you to recover your apt correctly.

For Remove Libreoffice (complete)

> sudo apt-get purge libreoffice*
>
> sudo dpkg --configure -a

As you know libreoffice package contains lot of other libreoffice packages like libreoffice-draw libreoffice-writer etc. So you have to put libreoffice* (* represent all packages who start with libreoffice and end with anything).

NOTE: if dpkg --configure -a give you any error then you have to remove these packages one by one with

> dpkg --purge package-name

Hope it will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks your your apt cache is out of date.

run `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get install libreoffice`

If that still doesn't work then edit your software sources and remove any PPAs or experemental repositories so your back to just the default ones and try again.

The best way to remove "extra" repositories is with  "software sources" from inside the System settings.

Answer (score 0):

I've same problem and this works for me

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2082867&page=2

Comment: Please provide the detailed steps to help everybody know the answer better.

Comment: Try to be more descriptive in the answer